# Amazon ItemSearch API reponse different from amazon.com search results

Tags: amazon-product-api

I am trying to figure out the right parameters for ItemSearch such that the API call will return the same result as on the website. Currently I am using these params it is not consistent with the website.

```
url_params = dict(
        Service='AWSECommerceService', 
        Operation='ItemSearch', 
        AssociateTag=AMAZON_ASSOCIATETAG,
        SearchIndex='All',
        AWSAccessKeyId=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,  
        Keywords=keywords,
        ResponseGroup='Small,OfferSummary,Images'
        )
```

For example if 'iphone%205s' is put in keywords, the API returns a list of iPhone protectors, while searching on the website gives iPhones as top results.

Answer (score 0):

I am also trying to figure out why this is for book searches. One possible answer I found online was that the websites search feature might use more elaborate queries than just one simple API call. For example, it may take into account other factors into the search (not sure what that might be but it may).